# Delete a case insensitive filename from a .zip file

Tags: linux, bash, zip

I appreciate the feedback, especially about asking better questions. I've been reading more about better etiquette here, and hope I'm not breaking any rules now. But I realize I worded my original question poorly. I've learned a bunch through this exercise, but ultimately, it's taken me less time to take a list of the offending files, and manually deleting the crap images. Thanks for all of the help! I'm moving onto more worthwhile uses of my time.

I've got thousands of `.zip` files in subdirectories with a few different errant images in them we'll call `crap.*`. But they're different cases in the filenames. The files could have different extensions and some additional character in front of or behind the `crap`, such as `123crap567.jpg` or `-crap-.gif`.

I'm trying to write a bash script for Linux to scan through the directories, find the zip's with the `CrAp.PNG`, and delete that file from within the zip. Below is my code I've got so far, but it's not working.

I believe I'm scanning through and finding the correct zip files, and identifying the exact name of the "crap files". But I'm getting:

> zip error: Invalid command arguments (specify just one action)

What am I doing wrong?

```
for i in *.zip; do
    [ -f "$i" ] || break
    f=$(zipinfo "$i" | grep -i -ho "\S*crap\S*")
    if [[ $f ]]; then
      zipinfo "$i" | grep -i -ho "\S*crap\S*" | xargs zip -d \'\*\/$i\'
    fi
done
```

Comment: In my Kubuntu `man zip` mentions support for `[]`. Instead of this contraption (with `zipinfo`, `grep` and `xargs`) use `zip -d "$i" '*[Cc][Rr][Aa][Pp]*'` (test it on some expendable files first). Since the question is "what am I doing wrong?", not "how can I do it better?" (see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)), this is not an answer; therefore only a comment. I think passing single-quotes to `xargs` (and ultimately to `zip`) and not double-quoting `$i` are wrong, but I haven't tested; and there may be more what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print out the value of each "$f", it is likely to be wrong. The version of `zipinfo` I have would print many lines and information you don't need - including file information - so the grep might not generate filenames properly:

```
$ zipinfo  zip_with_zips.zip
Archive:  zip_with_zips.zip
Zip file size: 234464 bytes, number of entries: 4
-rw-a--     6.3 fat      310 bx defN 22-Jan-27 16:22 2.txt
```

Try instead with `zipinfo -1 "$i"` in each place to show only the filenames, and `zip -d "$i"` at the end:

```
f=$(zipinfo -1 "$i" | grep -i -ho "\S*crap\S*")
if [[ $f ]]; then
  zipinfo -1 "$i" | grep -i -ho "\S*crap\S*" | xargs zip -d "$i"
fi
```

Comment: A warning: I don't know if in the filenames stored in a zip file it is possible to use special characters and dangerous ones (e.g. the newline, when a part of the name before the newline is the same of other file/dir names...). This is a general warning derived to _It is never a good idea to parse the output of `ls`_ and similar.